# Вам дана последовательность чисел заканчивающаяся -1. Выведете ее в обратном порядке без учета -1

Tags: python

Вам дана последовательность чисел заканчивающаяся -1. Выведете ее в обратном порядке без учета -1
Вот пример ввода и вывода
Sample Input:

1

2

3

4

-1

Sample Output:

4

3

2

1

```
a.append(int(input()))
a.append(int(input()))
a.append(int(input()))
a.append(int(input()))
element = a.pop()
print(element)
print(element)
print(element)
print(element)
```

вот мой код, почему-то не получается

Comment: Потому что ваш код не имеет отношения к задаче, для реализации данной задачи необходимо изучить циклы условия и массивы(или любой способ их заменить, например рекурсия и стек, список,.....)

Answer (score 0):

print (a[:-1][::-1]) вывод списка через срезы [4, 3, 2, 1]
a[:-1] - срез по последний элемент(отбросили последний элемент -1)
а[::-1] срез от начала до конца списка с шагом -1, то же что с последнего по первый

Comment: Ответ не на этот вопрос